# POSIX Message queues, errno 90, message too long

Tags: c, linux, posix

I am currently doing a minimal IPC using POSIX Message Queues. I have one pipe that only will pass `uint8_t`'s as commands and another pipe that will pass strings with a length up to 128 characters. The command pipe is working fine. But the stringpipe will always give me errno number 90, which means `message too long`. I have written a minimal example demonstrating the issue (please note: i kept it minimal, so there is no errorhandling whatsoever besides the error upon receiving).

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <mqueue.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int msg_size = 128;

int send()
{
    struct mq_attr attr = {0, 10, msg_size + 1, 0};
    mqd_t mq = mq_open("/test", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 00644, &attr);
    char msg[msg_size] = {0};
    strncpy(msg, "this_is_a_test", msg_size);
    mq_send(mq, msg, msg_size, 0);
}

int recv()
{
    struct mq_attr attr = {0, 10, msg_size + 1, 0};
    mqd_t mq = mq_open("/test", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 00644, &attr);
    char msg[msg_size] = {0};
    int res = mq_receive(mq, msg, msg_size, NULL);
    if (res == -1)
    {
        printf("Errno: %d\n", errno);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Message: %s\n", msg); 
    }
}

int main()
{
    send();
    recv();
    return 0;
}
```

Compile with:

```
g++ -o mq mq.c -lrt
```

Comment: why compile with a C++ compiler when there is no C++ code?  Suggest using `gcc`.   When compiling, always enable all the warnings.  for `gcc` / `g++` at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`   I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu99`.  For the posted code, the compiler will output many warning messages.  Fix those warnings.

Comment: 1) a message queue only needs to be opened once, regardless of the number of processes using that queue.  2)  the actual list of fields in the `struct mq_attr` depends on the implementation, so cannot use an initializer but rather set each field by field name, similar to: `mset( &attr, '\0', sizeof( attr ) ); attr.mq_maxmsg = 300;
  attr.mq_msgsize = MSG_SIZE;
  attr.mq_flags = 0;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read [the `mq_receive` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mq_receive.3.html) you will will see that `EMSGSIZE` means

> `msg_len` was **less** than the `mq_msgsize` attribute of the message queue

<sub>[Emphasis mine]</sub>

And that's true, you set the `mq_msgsize` attribute to `msg_size + 1` and then you receive `msg_size` which is one less than the `mq_msgsize` attribute.

You don't need that `+1` when setting the `mq_msgsize` attribute, just remove it.

Answer (score 0):

the following code

1. cleanly compiles
2. actually works
3. You do need to have a `/dev/mqueue` device already created.
4. do not use known system function names for your local function names
5. use `perror()` to properly output error messages.  Note: the output will automatically include the system message related to `errno`
6. note the usage of `(size_t)attr.mq_msgsize` in the call to `mq_receive()`
7. note only need to call `mq_open()` once
8. note the `mqd_t mqdes` and `struct mq_attr` variables are in the file global space so all the functions can see them.  An alternate possibility is to pass them as parameters.
9. note the MSG_SIZE is defined via `#define` so it does not consume space on the stack nor on the file global space and only needs to be defined once rather than in each function
10. header files that are not used in the code should not be included.
11. note the `attr` is cleared to all 0x00 before setting the individual fields
12. note that only the actual length of the message is specified in the call to mq_send(), so no trash is sent/received

and now the code

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <mqueue.h> // mq_open(), mq_send(), mq_receive()

//#include <errno.h>
//#include <time.h>
#include <string.h> // strncpy(), strlen()

#include <stdio.h>  // printf(), perror()
#include <stdlib.h> // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE

#define MSG_SIZE  (128)

static mqd_t mqdes = -1;
static struct mq_attr attr;

void sendQueue()
{
    char msg[ MSG_SIZE ] = {0};
    strncpy(msg, "this_is_a_test", MSG_SIZE);
    if( -1 == mq_send(mqdes, msg, strlen(msg), 5) )
    {
        perror( "mq_send failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    else
    {
        printf( "%s\n", "msg sent successfully");
    }
}

void recvQueue()
{
    char msg[ MSG_SIZE ] = {0};

    ssize_t res = mq_receive(mqdes, msg, (size_t)attr.mq_msgsize, NULL);
    if (res == -1)
    {
        perror("mq_receive failed");
    }

    else
    {
        printf("Message: %s\n", msg);
    }
}

int main( void )
{
    mode_t mode = S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IROTH | S_IWOTH;

    memset( &attr, 0x00, sizeof(struct mq_attr) );
    attr.mq_maxmsg = 3;
    attr.mq_msgsize = MSG_SIZE;
    attr.mq_flags = 0;
    attr.mq_curmsgs = 0;

    char *queueName = "/test";

    mqdes = mq_open( queueName, O_RDWR|O_CREAT, mode, &attr);
    if( -1 == mqdes )
    {
        perror( "mq_open failed");
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, mq_open successful


    sendQueue();
    recvQueue();
    return 0;
}
```